# Event after "remove_row" from context menu

Tags: handsontable

When the `remove_row` option is selected from the context menu, the row is deleted. Is there a way to fire an event with this removal? In particular, is there a way to grab the index of the row and fire a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what the `afterRemoveRow` callback is for. Take a look at all callbacks [here](http://handsontable.com/demo/callbacks.html).

The callback function after removing a row is fired with a row index and the amount of removed rows as arguments.

```
function (index, amount) {}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gzzrf5vd/)'s a working JSFiddle for demonstration.

Comment: This is the correct answer for my question, thanks, it still doesn't work however and just shows me the corner clone cell and nothing else. It feels like somewhere in my own implementation I must be overriding something or another so I will start debugging it knowing this solution should work.